# Why does this if executes while I have not given any input?

Tags: c++

Here is my code snippet:

```
int a;
if(a=8)
    cout<<"Its right";
else
    cout<<"Not at all";
getch();
return(0);
```

I'm getting the output `Its right` while I've not give any input there its just a assignment to the `a=8`.

`**Borland Compiler**` gives the following 2 warnings and executes the code.

> 1: Possible incorrect assignment (a=8)
>
> 2: 'a' is assigned a value that is never used.

Comment: What exactly are you asking? Most of the answers seem to assume that you want to know where you error is, but the use of `"Its right"` seems to indicate that you _intend_ the code to work as it does. I took the question to be why the compiler would emit warnings for (formally) correct code that does what you want it to. When you ask question, please consider including, you know, an actual question, rather than just posting a chunk of code and let the rest of us guess.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

When you write:

```
if(a=8)
```

You're *assigning* 8 to the variable a, and returning a, so you're effectively writing:

```
a = 8;
if(a)
```

This is non-zero, and hence treated as "true".

I (and the compiler) suspect you intended to write (note `==` instead of `=`):

```
if(a==8)
```

This is why you get the warnings.  (Note that, in this case, `a` is still uninitialized, so the behavior is undefined.  You will still get a warning, and may still return true...)

Comment: And again the if might be true. You can't be sure about the value an unitialized variable has :)

Comment: @George: Very true.  Edited to include that.

Comment: I understand the difference between `=` and `==`. If I use `==` instead `=` then the `else part will execute. So I want to know why is assign value is true and executing?

Comment: @arvik, the assignment operator evaluates the the value that was assigned, in this case `8`. Because `8` is nonzero, it counts as true in a Boolean context.

Comment: @avirk: I answer this - when you write a = 8, that entire thing returns a - so you're writing, effectively, `if (8)`, which is "true" in C++...

Answer (score 2):

`a = 8` assign `8` to `a` and returns the value of the assignment, that is `8`. `8` is different from 0 and thus is considered `true`. the test apsses, and the program outputs `"Its right"`.

you may have written `if ( a == 8 )` which correctly tests the value of `a` without changing its value.

Answer (score 2):

```
if(a=8)
```

implies assign a value of 8 to a and then use it to evaluate for the if statement. Since 8 is nonzero it essentially translates to TRUE (any value that is non-zero is true).

Answer (score 2):

The first warning is because it's a frequent typo to write `=` in a condition test where you meant `==`. The philosophy behind the warning is that it's a lesser burden for a programmer to rewrite `if(a=b)` to, say `if((a=b)!=0)` in the few cases he wants that, than to spend frustrating hours debugging the results if he mistakenly got an assignment instead of a comparison.

The second warning is just what it says: It looks like a mistake to have a local variable that you assign a value to but never use.

Since they are just warnings, you're free to ignore them if you think you know what you're doing. The compiler may even provide a way for you to turn them off.

Answer (score 2):

Everyone else's answer is correct :)

```
if (a = 8) // Sets a to be 8 (and returns true so the if statement passes)
if (a == 8) // Check to see if a is equal to 8
```

I just want to add that I always (force of habit!) write if statements this way :

```
if (8 == a) {
```

Now, if I miss out one of the `=`, the compiler doesn't give me a warning, it gives me an error :)

Answer (score 1):

You need a == (double equals). Single = is an assignment; when treated as an expression as you have done here, it evaluates to the value assigned, in this case 8. 0 is treated as False and anything else is True, so (a=8) == 8 == True.